# Solving equation with exponential, not numerically

Tags: exponential-function, roots

Doing a homework of a related course, I reached to the following equation:

$$1 + 2x = e^x$$

By inspection, $x$ can be zero, but plotting $f(x) = 1 + 2x - e^x$, I can see that it has another root near 2. For my problem (It is a physics problem), due to dimension constraints, $x$ cannot be zero, nor can it be negative, so that solution around 1.25 is the solution I am looking for, however I don't want a numerical approximation. Is there a way of approximating this, more theoretically? (I mean using taylor series or something?, or getting the exact solution if it is possible?)

Comment: Why is a numerical solution not desired here? It might be possible to use the Lambert W function otherwise, as a Taylor series would also lead to numerical approximation

Comment: Why is a Taylor series approximation acceptable but a numeric approximation not?  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2B2x%3De%5Ex) finds the root to be about $1.25$

Comment: I don't want a raw number, because I simplified it, x in reality is: physical constants multiplied by a variable, so I need an expression using these physical constants

Comment: Well, I guess it can't be helped, but using newton raphson or something to find the solution...

Comment: Yeah the best you can do is use as much pricision as is allowed, as I said before there is an answer in terms of the Lambert W function but it still yields a large decimal answer

Comment: @dpalma The WA link posted by Ross Millikan gives the closed form in terms of the Lambert W function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that we know the solution is about $1.25$ we can use the Taylor series very well.  Let $y=x-\frac 54$ and your equation becomes $2y+\frac 72=e^{\frac 54}e^y$  with $y$ rather small (about $0.0064$).  Use as many terms of the Taylor series as you feel like.  If we use the quadratic, we get $2y+\frac 72=e^{\frac 54}(1+y+\frac {y^2}2)$ or $$\frac 12e^{\frac 54}y^2 +(e^{\frac 54}-2)y+e^{\frac 54}-\frac 72=0$$ which you can solve with the quadratic formula.  It will be quite accurate because we expanded near the root.  It would be even more accurate  to use $y=x-1.2564$ to make $y$ small and the neglected terms of the Taylor series smaller.  I don't understand why this is better than a numeric approach, but it meets the request.

Answer (score 1):

One might exploit the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1) to find that

$$x=-\frac12-W_k\left(-\frac12e^{-1/2}\right),~k=-1,0$$

Where we have

$$W_0\left(-\frac12e^{-1/2}\right)=-\frac12$$

[$$W_{-1}\left(-\frac12e^{-1/2}\right)\approx-1.756431208626169677$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=productlog(-1,-e%5E(-1%2F2)%2F2))

Thus, the solutions are given by

$$x=0,~\color{red}{1.25}6431208626169677$$

---

One might wish to exploit different approximations of the Lambert W function here.  For example,

$$\begin{align}_0W_{-1}(x)&=\ln(-x)\\_1W_{-1}(x)&=\ln(-x)-\ln(-\ln(-x))\\_2W_{-1}(x)&=\ln(-x)-\ln(-\ln(-x)+\ln(-\ln(-x)))\\_3W_{-1}(x)&=\ln(-x)-\ln(-\ln(-x)+\ln(-\ln(-x)+\ln(-\ln(-x))))\\\vdots\\W_{-1}(x)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}~_nW_{-1}(x)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a natural way to solve this theoretically. Let $a$ be the solution you're looking for. Then, an exact description of $a$ is given by

- $a > 0$ and $1 + 2a = e^a$.

I can understand being uncomfortable with this; we spend years of being drilled on what solutions to homework problems are "supposed" to look like, and the above solution doesn't look like that.

But this isn't a homework question — what matters is how well this description satisfies *your* needs.

This formulation is already good enough to do a fair amount of symbolic calculation. For example:

- In any formula containing $e^a$, you could replace it with $1 + 2a$
- In any formula containing $a$, you could replace it with $\frac{1}{2}(e^a - 1)$
- If you multiply an inequality by $a$, you know the inequalities stay the same (i.e. they aren't reversed)

Also, you've already identified that $1.25 < a < 1.26$, so in a situation where you need a numerical value to make estimates, you already have one. If you need more precision than that, the formula lends itself to a variety of ways of getting that.

---

In summary, you should see if the description of $a$ that you already have is good enough for your purposes, before you go through a lot of effort to produce a more complicated and cumbersome description of $a$.

And if you do have a specific need that does not appear to be satisfied, ask a question specifically about that need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newton's method:

$f(x) = 1 + 2x - e^{x}$ so $f'(x) = 2 - e^{x}$.

Start with a reasonable approximation to the unknown root and substitute it into $x_2 = x_1 - \frac{f(x_1)}{f'(x_1)}$ and repeat until the answer converges.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the analytical solution in terms of Lambert function (as Simply Beautiful Art used in his/her  answer), only numerical methods (as shown in many other answers) can be used.

Similar to Taylor expansions, we also could use [Padé approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant). Built around $x=\frac 54$, the simplest one would write
$$2x+1-e^x \approx \frac{\frac{7-2 e^{5/4}}{2} +\frac{\left(-16+9 e^{5/4}-2 e^{5/2}\right)
   }{4
   \left(e^{5/4}-2\right)} \left(x-\frac{5}{4}\right)}{1-\frac{e^{5/4} }{2
   \left(e^{5/4}-2\right)}\left(x-\frac{5}{4}\right)}$$ Set the umerator equal to $0$ to get $$x=\frac 54-\frac{2 \left(e^{5/4}-2\right) \left(2 e^{5/4}-7\right)}{16-9 e^{5/4}+2 e^{5/2}}\approx 1.256430949$$ while the exact solution, already given by Simply Beautiful Art, is $x\approx 1.256431209$.

We could continue using $[1,n]$ Padé approximants and get the following results just solving a linear equation. What is given below are decimal representations of analytical formulae.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 &  1.256479745 \\
 1 &  1.256430949 \\
 2 &  1.256431210 \\
 3 &  1.256431209
\end{array}
\right)$$